# ajax json request , always returning error

Tags: ajax, json

Hello i've got a problem with ajax json request. Im always getting an error, even if the requests are succeeded. At the moment i have this code:

```
function sumbitLoginForm(user, pass) {
    if (user.trim() == '' || pass.trim() == '') {
        alert("You must enter username and password!");
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'https://url.php',
            dataType : 'json',
            data : {
                userlogin : user,
                userpass : pass
            },
            contentType: "application/json;",
            success : function(data) {
                $("#images").html("uspeshno");
            },
            error : function(data) {
                $("#images").html("greshka");
            }
        });
        }

    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    clearPageInputs();
    $("#submitButton").click(function() {
        sumbitLoginForm($("#username").val(), $("#password").val());
    });
});
```

Im always getting an error , no matter what username and password i type . But the status of request is changing , if i type correct user and pass i get status 302 Moved temporarly , but when i type wrong user or pass i get status 200 OK . What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: and what clearPageInputs() is doing?

Comment: `function clearPageInputs() {
 $("input[type=text]").val('');
}`

Comment: error in your url. look into error body, and you will find truly url there

Comment: check your url and if your php code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**PRG Pattern and Ajax**

It looks like your server returns a HTTP 200 status code when the userid and password will not validate. This is proper behavior, as HTTP error codes not meant for application errors, but for HTTP protocol errors.

When the userid and password are matched succesfully, you are redirected to another page. This is also normal behavior, e.g. to prevent other people to re-use your login credentials using the back key.

This is called the Post/Redirect/Get pattern.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

The problem is that the PRG pattern does not play nice with Ajax applications. The redirect should be handled by the browser. It is therefore transparent for the jQuery code. The Ajax html response will be the page that is mentioned in the Location header of the 302. Your Ajax application will not be able to see that it is being redirected. So your are stuck.

In one of my projects I solved this on the server side. If I detected an Ajax call, I would not send a redirect but a normal 200 response. This only works if you have access to the server code.

If you cannot change the redirect for your Ajax calls, then you can parse the response headers or the html to see if you were being redirected and act accordingly. Probably the login will set a cookie, so you might try and look for the presence of that cookie.